# Is it possible to pause event listeners in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

When debugging in Chrome, occasionally I want to pause event listeners while flipping to dev tools.

In this particular instance, I'm debugging the Selectize dropdown plug-in, and want to click around in the Elements panel in the dev tools, but as soon as I toggle to the dev tools window, the dropdown closes up because the window loses focus.

Is there a way to pause state in a web app in Chrome?

Comment: You could edit the code to use a boolean as a toggle for execution of code in the event listener.